# GROUP_CONCAT of SUMs

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, group-concat

I have two select-queries which both give correct results:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS "sum1" FROM table GROUP BY id1
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS "sum2" FROM table GROUP BY id1, id2
```

`sum1` is the sum of all `sum2`-items and I want a query that gives me a result of `sum1` and a GROUP_CONCAT of all `sum2`-items. But how can I define the GROUP BY inside the GROUP_CONCAT for the `sum2`-items element?

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS "sum1", GROUP_CONACAT(SUM(value) AS "sum2" ... (?))
FROM table GROUP BY id1
```

Comment: All your previous questions are better than this one. This definitely feels like a step backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should solve it using sub query, use the following query, i believe it will solve your problem

```
select sum(t.part_sum) as sum1, group_concat(t.part_sum) as sum2 from (select sum(value) as part_sum from table group by id1, id2) as t
```

Comment: I get an error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't' at line 1`